# Integrity Constraint - Parent Key not Found

Tags: sql, database, oracle

For my data basing and SQL class we had to make a bunch of tables and our teach gave us some data to copy and paste into it.

I can't get it to accept the data because every time I do it tells me there's something wrong with the foreign key on the table because there's no parent key.

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERDETAILS
(
ORDERID NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
PRODUCTID NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
UNITPRICE NUMBER(8,2) NOT NULL,
QUANTITY NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
DISCOUNT NUMBER(2,2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_ORDERDETAILS PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
CONSTRAINT ORDERDETAILS_PRODUCTS_fk FOREIGN KEY(PRODUCTID) REFERENCES
PRODUCTS(PRODUCTID),
CONSTRAINT ORDERDETAILS_DISCOUNT_CK CHECK(0 <= DISCOUNT AND 1 >= DISCOUNT),
CONSTRAINT ORDERDETAILS_QUANTITY_CK CHECK(QUANTITY > 0),
CONSTRAINT ORDERDETAILS_UNITPRICE_CK CHECK(UNITPRICE >= 0)
);
```

Here's the table it's referencing too because i don't know if that's the issue or not.

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS
(
PRODUCTID NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
PRODUCTNAME VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
SUPPLIERID NUMBER(8),
CATEGORYID NUMBER(8),
QUANITYPERUNIT VARCHAR2(20),
UNITPRICE NUMBER(8,2),
UNITSINSTOCK NUMBER(6),
UNITSONORDER NUMBER(6),
RECORDERLEVEL NUMBER(6),
DISCONTINUED NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_PRODUCTS PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCTID),
CONSTRAINT PRODUCTS_SUPPLIERS_fk FOREIGN KEY(SUPPLIERID) REFERENCES
SUPPLIERS(SUPPLIERID),
CONSTRAINT PRODUCTS_CATEGORIES_fk FOREIGN KEY(CATEGORYID) REFERENCES
CATEGORIES(CATEGORYID),
CONSTRAINT PRODUCTS_UNITPRICE_CK CHECK(UNITPRICE >= 0),
CONSTRAINT PRODUCTS_RECORDERLEVEL_CK CHECK(RECORDERLEVEL >= 0),
CONSTRAINT PRODUCTS_UNITSINSTOCK_CK CHECK(UNITSINSTOCK >= 0),
CONSTRAINT PRODUCTS_UNITSONORDER_CK CHECK(UNITSONORDER >= 0)
);
```

Thanks in advanced!

[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaTfj.png)

[Data in products table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wR0Be.png)

Comment: In which table you have issue, both have foreign keys

Comment: Sorry, it's with the OrderDetails one

I'll post a picture of the error code I get too

Comment: Draw yourself a diagram of the tables, showing which tables are the parents of the others. Then load from the "top" down, any tables without parents first, then all of their direct children. Then their direct children, and so on until all are loaded.

Comment: My teacher actually gave us a diagram to work off of. Want me to post it?

Comment: Do you have data in PRODUCTS table?

Comment: @RamachandraReddy yes

Comment: Can you post sample data in PRODUCTS data?

Comment: @RamachandraReddy done

Comment: PRODUCTID in PRODUCTS Table is Integer, but the PRODUCTID you are using while inserting into ORDERDETAILS table has decimals. That is causing the issue.

Comment: All my primary keys are declared like that, and all my other foreign keys work